# Compute a simple expectation with Poisson process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, poisson-distribution

I encountered a simple question about computing the following expectation:
$$E \left[C^{N_t}\right]$$ where $C>0$ is a fixed constant and $N_t$ is standard Poisson process

My thinking is follows:
$$\begin{array}{l}
E{C^{{N_t}}} = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {{C^k}P\left( {{N_t} = k} \right)}  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {{C^k}{e^{ - \lambda t}}\frac{{{{\left( {\lambda t} \right)}^k}}}{{k!}}} \\
\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}&{}&{}
\end{array} = {e^{ - \lambda t}}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{{{\left( {C\lambda t} \right)}^k}}}{{k!}}}  = {e^{ - \lambda t}}{e^{C\lambda t}} = {e^{\left( {C - 1} \right)\lambda t}}
\end{array}$$
The thing bothers me is that $N_t$ is a process but what I'm doing here is simply treat it as a random variable. Is this thinking correct?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you include $k{}={}0$ in the expectation? I think this is necessary to justify the final step. Furthermore, the fact that it is Poisson process means that, for each $t$, one has a Poisson distributed random variable $N_t$ with parameter $t\lambda$; so you are fine.

Comment: It is supposed to be $(\lambda t)^k$, mot $\lambda t^k$. So the calculation needs to be corrected.

Comment: @AndréNicolas , Indeed! I missed that (despite quoting the correct parameter).

Comment: Indeed $N_t$ is a random variable, not a process, only $(N_t)_{t\geqslant0}$ is a  process. The expectation $E(C^{N_t})$ has to do with the distribution of $N_t$ only, not with the distribution of the whole process.

Comment: Thank you guys :) I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general random processes are functions of a parameter where each instance is a random variable. Your thinking is correct.